Como desplegar proyecto laravel que usa websockets en servidor ubuntu 22.04
Estoy desplegando un proyecto en laravel 8 que usa websockets, estoy usando clounding.io un servidor ubuntu 22.04, y nginx, el proyecto ya me muestra en la ip publica todo normal me logeo, pero en la consola me arroja varios errores que son los siguientes:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://200.234.237.47/app/bXl0ZW1z?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed:


Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://sockjs-mt1.pusher.com/pusher/app/bXl0ZW1z/877/rmaai7km/xhr?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&t=1717609068153&n=27' from origin 'http://200.234.237.47' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


POST http://sockjs-mt1.pusher.com/pusher/app/bXl0ZW1z/877/rmaai7km/xhr?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&t=1717609068153&n=27 net::ERR_FAILED


app.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'ws://200.234.237.47:6001/app/bXl0ZW1z?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Para correr el comando php artisan websocket:serve uso supervisorctl, ya he verificado puerto y configuración del websocket, cabe indicar que ese error me salia en local, pero era debido a que no estaba corriendo el comando php artisan websocket:serve y cuando ya lo ejecutaba ya no daba ese error, pero en mi servidor el comando está corriendo con supervisor y sigue saliendo ese error.
Es primera vez que subo un sistema laravel que usa websockets en un sistema ubuntu :)

le agradezco de antemano su ayuda.


Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://sockjs-mt1.pusher.com...' from origin 'http://200.234.237.47' has been blocked by CORS hay un tema de que pusher no reconoce la ip como origen valido, si no usas una cuenta pusher: fijate https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/96#issuecomment-727599890 si usas una cuenta pusher: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authorizing-users/
